# Error TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable in Flask

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Very good day!

So, what i need to do, if i have an error **TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable** in Flas

```py
file = flask.request.files.getlist['propert_photo[]']
TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Фотографии</label>
    <input name = "propert_photo[]" type="file" accept="image/png" multiple="" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
</div>
```

pls help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file = flask.request.files.getlist['propert_photo[]']`
should be
`file = flask.request.files.getlist('propert_photo[]')`

`getlist` is a method, and a method call uses `()` and not `[]`.

"Subscriptable" in Python refers to whether or not you can use the square bracket syntax (like `a[0]`) on an object (or, in other words: whether or not it implements the `__getitem__()` method). Indeed, a method/function object does not enable this syntax.

Comment: You're very welcome :)

Comment: okay, just a moment, thats an error (You can accept an answer in 8 minutes) so i waiting

Comment: good luck and thank you too!!